# Magento 1 - Email Templates - Display Text Based on Variable Result

Tags: magento-1.9

Within an email template, I have the following variable: {{var order_status}} This inserts (for example) Status 1, Status 2, or Status 3 into the body of the email.

What I want the template to do is:

If {{var order_status}} equals "Status 1", then display text relating to this status.

OR if{{var order_status}} equals "Status 2", then display text relating to this status instead.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :-**

```
{{if order_status == "Status 1"}}
     <p>"Status 1"</p>
{{/if}}

{{if order_status == "Status 2"}}
     <p>"Status 2"</p>
{{/if}}
```